# Access index while mapping 2D array

Tags: reactjs

I have a 2D array that I'm mapping in jsx
I am trying to access the outer array index inside the second mapping func
Any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: please share an example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  let arr = [
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9],
  ];

  {arr.map((innerArr, idx) => {
    return innerArr.map((item) => {
      return (
        <p>
          {idx}: {item}
        </p>
      );
    });
  })}
```